# Call remote ejb on wildfly 8.0 without jboss dependencies in classpath

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, ejb-3.1, wildfly

I'm running a very simple remote ejb on a Wildfly 8.0 server. I'm trying to call the ejb from a standalone client.

I've downloaded the wildly quickstart from https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/ejb-remote and it runs fine.

However, I don't want any dependencies to jboss in my client.

The only examples I've found for calling a remote ejb running on wildfly has dependencies to jboss. You need jboss-ejb-client.properties or EJBClientConfiguration, a dependency to jboss-ejb-client and a dependency to jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec.

I thought it was possible to do this with the standard JavaEE API without any specific appserver dependencies in my client.

Am I wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You are wrong at this point ;-)

To communicate remotely with your server you have to add to your app classpath library that knows how to communicate with that server.

Java EE API is just the set of interfaces. Their implementation is provided by application servers such as wildfly or glassfish, so you have to add e.g. jboss-client.jar in order to make a connection.

Remote communication with java clients are done differently on every server implementation. Even when lookup looks the same (you usually create initial context and so on), you are providing custom factories in property files that point to specific JNDI implementation for given application server and those classes must be provided in client classpath.